# pyqt context menu with multiple qlineedit widgets

Tags: python-3.x, widget, contextmenu, pyqtgraph

I hope someone can help me out with this.

I have a pyqtgraph context menu and want to add my own Z-Axis. I can create a qlineedit widget but I am not able to create multiple widget on the same line in the context menu as show below (e.g. radio button and 2 text boxes on same line)

[image]

As a minimum I would like to achieve:-

Z Axis -> [input value], string, [input value]

I've had a look in qmenu but couldn't find what I needed. Anyone know how to achieve this.

Also if anyone knows how to change the size of the X Axis qlineedit boxes and make them bigger it would be great as they are a bit squashed as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on a different forum was able to help me with the answer so I thought I would also post it here for future users.

What you have to do is go into the site-packages for python and find pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ViewBox/. In there are several files called

> axisCtrlTemplate_*.py

A couple of lines down in the ui_form is the following line which you just need to increase the width (e.g. 450)

> Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(450, 16777215))

Hey presto fixed.

Also in the same location is a file called

> ViewBoxMenu.py

you can see how the context menu is written here and I will use this information to create my min and max values which are created in a ui (qtdesigner) and then added to the menu